# angularjs not including node_modules (minification and annotation)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, iis

i am working on a small angularjs project

and i imported ngRoute using :

> npm install angular-route -S

my index.js looks like:

```
import angular from 'angular';

import {nv_morts} from './components/calculator/mortsList/morts';

import 'angular-route/angular-route';


angular.module('app.starter', ['ngRoute'
]).config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/Calculators", nv_morts);
});
```

webpack.config:

```
 module: {
     loaders: [

       // load and compile javascript
       { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader:"babel", query: { presets: ['es2015', 'stage-1'] } },

       // load css and process less
       { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css"},

       // load JSON files and HTML
       { test: /\.json$/, loader: "json" },
       { test: /\.html$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader:"raw" },

       // load fonts(inline base64 URLs for <=8k)
       { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|otf)$/, loader: "file" },
       { test: /\.woff(2)?$/, loader: "url?limit=8192&minetype=application/font-woff"},

       // load images (inline base64 URLs for <=8k images)
       {test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'}
     ]   }
```

and i have a script in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "prestart": "npm install",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "bundle": "cp src/index.html dist/ & webpack -p ./dist/bundle.js"
  }
```

when i work locally (localhost:8080) everything is working fine
when i execute the command

> npm run build

it build the files index.html & bundle.js in "dist" folder

but when i put this filed in the IIS folder i get:

> Failed to instantiate module app.starter due to:
>   Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: t

if i remove the dependency on ngRoute it works fine as well on IIS

why isn't it including the ngRoute in the final bundle.js?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

OK So i solved it :-)

the problem was in the Minification and Annotaion.

this link [AngularJs Minification & Annotation](http://bguiz.github.io/js-standards/angularjs/minification-and-annotation/)

was very helpful.

my code was not using minification safe dependencies.

for example:

in index.js i should have done:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/Calculators", nv_morts)}]);
```

and when i inject services to other services i needed to use the same pattern like the index.js

and inside the components where i inject services i needed to use the $inject

for example:

```
class mortsController {

    /* @ngInject */
    constructor(MortsMngr) {
        this.newMortName = '';
        this.mortsManager = MortsMngr;
        this.savedMorts = MortsMngr.mortsList;

        MortsMngr.fetchMortsList();
    }  
}

mortsController.$inject = ['MortsMngr'];

export const nv_morts = {
    bindings: {},
    template: template,
    controller: mortsController,
    controllerAs: 'Morts'
}
```

notice that the line:

> mortsController.$inject = ['MortsMngr'];

made the different.

hope it helped anyone